# How do I debug a request done by drupal's simpletest internal browser?

Tags: drupal, netbeans, xdebug, simpletest

I'm using Xammp with Xdebug and Netbeans for development and debugging of a Drupal site. When debugging tests I can easily debug the main thread running the test but I can't hook up to the requests done by the simpletest internal browser or the requests done by selenium. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which drupal version are you using?

Comment: It's drupal 7. I get around this for now by setting xdebug to always connect to the remote host, setting a fixed idekey and starting the debug session in Netbeans after starting the test. That way xdebug connects to the browser even when a request is done from a selenium test where the xdebug cookie is not present and Netbeans is free to receive connections because it hasn't hooked to the main test thread.

Comment: @dhinchliff, that seems to be your best (and only) option I think.